# Magento filter configurable products by all simples attached

Tags: filter, magento2, configurable

If anybody know if Magento are planning to fix this issue?

**Pre-condition: **configurable products are catalog/search visible. Simple products are not shown individually

When you filter products by attributes Magento shows configurable in the result. But in reality noone simple product of this configurable doesn't match all filter attributes.

Example:
We have follow category with preselected filters https://lexicon.leitz.org/en/product-categories/circular-sawblades.html?base_application=51380&bore_size_interface=93100&diameter=93188-93188:

base_application - 51380
bore_size_interface - 93100
diameter - 93188

No one simple matches all 3 conditions, so there should be no result.
But Magento shows cofigurable (see DB screenshot), as this configurable product with simple products which have specified attribute options by the filter

Maybe smb knows if Magento is planning to fix it?
Or can advice the fast workaround for this issue?

Comment: you may need to customize the catalog search functionality in your Magento store to achieve the desired behavior. This would likely involve custom development to modify how products are filtered and displayed based on attribute conditions.